# Can i use sql server reporting services (SSRS , SSIS etc) for multilingual report generation?

Tags: reporting-services

I work on few .net projects which create reports in 'English' in pdf file. 
Report contains few texts as well as few graphs in it.

So my question is can i design an interface which will allow user to upload this generated pdf report and convert it in any other language using sql server reporting service. 
     OR 
Is it easy to do using simple asp.net ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Are you asking if you can upload PDF files containing reports and have SSRS or SSIS translate them into other languages, or are you asking if you can create a report definition that produces PDF reports in different languages? The first is beyond my ability, the second I could give you some pointers on.

Comment: Yes Robert you are right .... i want to convert my pdf file (which also contains few graphs) to some other language from English. 
so steps will be ---
(1) I will upload my my pdf file which is in English.
(2) Select the desired language and click on 'convert button'.
(3) then the logic written will convert the pdf containts into that language and again save the file in PDF.

So to explain more about my query - 
(1) Can we do this using SSRS or SSIS.
(2) OR we can easily do it in normal asp.net

Comment: I won't say it can't be done (or even that it's hard!) but I don't know how to do that, Sorry :( If you find a way to do it please post back, it sounds useful in many situations.